# NSGA-II algorithm for feature selection

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

Recently, I have submitted a journal paper, and one of the reviewers suggests me to do some comparison experiments. In the suggested paper he/she provided, the authors use the NSGA-II algorithm to optimize his proposed novel two-objective function. And in the paper, the author have indicated that he had modified the original NSGA-II algorithm. **To avoid solutions with multiple selections of the same feature, the author have changed the random initialization of the chromosome population and also modified the crossover and mutation operators.**

In my opinion, the author may initialize the population in some kind of deterministic way. In original NSGA-II algorithm, the initialization, the crossover and the mutation almost all are randomized. I think the author
have recorded the optimal subset, and just randomize the remain chromosomes, so the have-selected features can't be selected again. I don't know if I had the correct understanding.

I have just learned about multi-objective evolutionary algorithms for a few days, and much have confused me. 
Could someone who are familiar with the NSGA-II give me some advice on how to modify the standard NSGA-II algorithm to fit the author's method?
I'm also very appreciated that one can provide some references or links.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please give the reference to the paper you are talking about?

Comment: Hi, Benoît, the paper link is http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=05161332. Its title is "A Novel Approach to the Selection of Spatially Invariant Features for the Classification of Hyperspectral Images With Improved Generalization Capability". Starting from the bottom-left of page 3187, the authors described the modified NSGA-II algorithm.